# Many PG Clusters on more than one machine

Tags: postgresql, repmgr, patroni

I want to run ~10k PostgreSQL clusters.

Each cluster will be quite small with moderate traffic.

I have will have roughly 100 virtual machines. Each VM should run roughly 100 clusters. Each cluster should run in one container.

100 VMs. Each running 100 containers. One cluster per container --> 10k clusters

Features which are not available from PG out-of-the-box:

- If I create a new cluster I need to check: Which VM has room for a new cluster?
- I want to be able to move a cluster to a different VM

Before I re-invent the wheel: Is there already a PostgreSQL-way to handle such a scenario?

Does it make sense to use a [Kubernetes Postgres-Operator](https://blog.flant.com/comparing-kubernetes-operators-for-postgresql/) or Patroni?

Background: It will be some kind of open source learning/teaching environment. Each user should get full database superuser permissions. That's why it is not enough to give each user a database. Each user needs a cluster. At least that's my current impression. Please leave a comment if you have an idea for a different architecture.

Comment: Hmmm... I know very little about this, but would you not be better with 100 Containers? Less overhead? Do your users require persistent storage? There's the pg_quota tool [here](https://github.com/hlinnaka/pg_quota) which might be of use - should really be in the main code IMHO - it's obviously very important for enterprises... although maybe not - businesses would probably only have one primary server - dbas can keep an eye on disk space - we used to to this on Oracle! Anyway,  best of luck with your project!

Comment: thank you for your comment. I updated the question: Each cluster should run in one container. Is it more clear now? If not, please leave a comment.

Comment: You're still talking about VMs - for me, a VM is a full OS whereas a container is very different - but the distinction is becoming [less hard](https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/)... However, I think that you just say containers if you're not planning on running OS's on top of other OS's!

Comment: Goal: 10k clusters. 100 VMs. Each running 100 containers --> 10k

Comment: How many real machines? What's their spec? I hope you're not planning to run all of this on a Raspberry Pi box? :-)

Comment: If the project starts, then we won't be responsible for real machines. We will rent VMs.

Answer (score 2):

> Features which are not available from PG out-of-the-box:
>
> - If I create a new cluster I need to check: Which VM has room for a new cluster?
> - I want to be able to move a cluster to a different VM

Neither of the above is, could be, or should be the Postgres' responsibility. Yours is not an HA cluster, but simply a constellation of independent Postgres instances, so Patroni won't help you either.

Both features you want is exactly why container orchestration software, such as Kubernetes, exist. Whether you want to use an operator to manage Postgres instance deployments or maintain them yourself is for you to decide.